# iphoto and iphone

Tags: photos.app, iphone

I transferred my photos from the iphone to my mac. 
questions:
1. How do I copy, transfer or delete more than 1 at the same time?to a new carpet, album or usb?
2. Once in my mac computer i need to open a file, carpet or album to save them in order or by topic. How do I do this.

Comment: what's a carpet, in this context? Bad Google translate?

Comment: How do you transfer your photos?

Comment: Saving the photos by order in Finder? I don't think that's possible as you can order them, but once you select the order operations (name, date, etc) it's hard to put them back in the order again. I suggest sorting them into folders or using the tags that Mac OSX comes with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Standard Keyboard Shortcuts should work in Photos

1. `Cmd + Click` - To select individual photos
2. `Click` and then `Shift+Click` to select all photos in between the 2 clicks
3. `Shift Cmd E` - To select the export location
4. Drag and drop to a new album after selecting in step 1 and 2